# Свернуть массив объектов по одинаковым ключам

Tags: javascript

Как свернуть массив объектов по одинаковым ключам, с такой логикой?
Как можно проще, чтобы и в IE работало.

from

```
let arr = [{'red':100},{'blue':300},{'red':200},{'green':700}];
```

to

```
let arr2 = [{'red':[100, 200]},{'blue':300},{'green':700}];
```

Comment: Замените `reduce` и `find` в моем ответе на циклы. А `Object.keys` на `for(var key in el) break;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arr = [{'red':100},{'blue':300},{'red':200},{'green':700}];
let arr1 = arr.reduce((res, el) => {
  let key = Object.keys(el)[0];
  let item = res.find(el1 => Object.keys(el1)[0] == key);
  if (!item) {
    item = { [key]: el[key] };
    res.push(item);
  } else {
    if (!item[key].length)
      item[key] = [item[key]];
    item[key].push(el[key]);
  }
  return res;
}, []);
console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое! Здесь ньюанс в том, что значения одинаковых ключей должны в массив собираться

Comment: @Marina Да, я уже обратил на это внимание.